# Geometry Nodes: scaling random faces does not work, scaling manually selected faces does. Why?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I used the curve to mesh modifier to instance a square grid into a curve.
I want to uniformly scale random segments of the resulting "tube" in the xy plane.

Capturing the indexes of the faces I use them to address a pair of faces (top and bottom of tube) to scale.

Index of top face = `4n-1`

Index of bottom face = `4n-3`

Entering numbers according to these functions manually works as expected:
(`n=55` in this example)
[image]

Using nodes to calculate random numbers DOESNT NOT WORK. WHY?
(only one of the two adressed faces is selected properly, the "counterpart" (face on the bottom of tube in example) is not adressed/in another place as expected for some reason
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't write in all caps in the title or body of any posts, it is the written equivalent of shouting, is [harder to read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Readability) and may be [considered rude](https://en.w

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is because you have a random value per face index. That means different faces of the same ring may have a different random value.

You can divide the index by 4 (as 4 faces per ring), input that in a boolean random as ID so that all 4 faces of the same ring will have the same boolean value.

Then pick opposite faces which are odd or even (unmute the 'not' node eventually) depending on the opposite faces you want to scale.

[image]

Comment: +1 i had a solution as well - but it was not as elegant and clever as yours!

Comment: @Chris, thanks to say that!

Comment: @lemon Nice solution!  thought the index node uses vertex indexes by default. what makes the index be the face index here? or is it just that their effect is identical in this case due to math shenanigens? that was the whole reason i wanted to capture the face indexes in the first place.

Comment: "Scale elements" is set to "face", that's why the index in the 'field' going among the node tree is also a face index. Saying it another way: index is the index of what we are talking about when it's used to transform a given geometry.

Comment: @lemon they should really add a symbol to the index node to represent what kind of index it outputs. do you know where i can suggest that? especially since they literally added icons for vertex/edge/face for the measuring tape tool recently

Comment: sinwar, this is not so simple, because the same "index" node could output into two different fields (for instance, face and vertex).

Comment: but you can share your ideas about it here for instance: https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/?sorting=hot